# My bot isnt sending the embed that I have in my code

Tags: javascript, discord

My bot isn't sending the embed that I coded. Is there any problems in the code that i have?  Ive been working on this for like 2 days and its still giving me trouble.

Main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS"] }, {partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'website'){
        client.commands.get('website').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
});
```

Embed code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'website',
    description: "website",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setTitle('WEBSITE')
        .setURL('https://brodydurrett2.wixsite.com/teamban')

        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive an error when this command is executed?

Comment: I do not. I send the command in discord and it doesn't respond.

Comment: @RohanS Do you have any suggestions?